# Wait until a list of jquery ajax request are done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

It is almost the same with this question: [Wait until all jQuery Ajax requests are done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-request-are-done)

But my question is imporve:

That I'm doing many ajax requests, and I save them in an array:

```
var events = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    events.push($.ajax({...}));
}

$.when(events).done(function() {
   // do something when all requests are done.
});
```

As the related question tells, the $.when method takes **some `jqXHR` object in order**, but here I want **a list of them taken**.

And I read the documents in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/#jQuery-when-deferreds, but the method seemed not supporting this case (passing a list of `jqXHR` to `$.when` function)

How could it be? Plz help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need pass the promises as an argument list(like `$.when(promise1, promise2, promise3)`) to [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/), not as an array so use [Function.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

```
$.when.apply($, events).then(function() {
   // do something when all requests are done.
});
```

Comment: Oh, simple javascript basis, it works! Thank you.